# ansible - Incorrect type. Expected "object"

Tags: ansible

## site.yaml

```
---
- name: someapp deployment playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - secrets.yml
  environment:
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "{{ lookup('env', 'AWS_DEFAULT_VERSION') | default('ca-central-1', true) }}"
  tasks:
    - include: tasks/create_stack.yml
    - include: tasks/deploy_app.yml
```

---

## create_stack.yml

```
---
- name: task to create/update stack
  cloudformation:
    stack_name: someapp
    state: present
    template: templates/stack.yml
    template_format: yaml
    template_parameters:
      VpcId: "{{ vpc_id }}"
      SubnetId: "{{ subnet_id }}"
      KeyPair: "{{ ec2_keypair }}"
      InstanceCount: "{{ instance_count | default(1) }}"
      DbSubnets: "{{ db_subnets | join(',') }}"
      DbAvailabilityZone: "{{ db_availability_zone }}"
      DbUsername: "{{ db_username }}"
      DbPassword: "{{ db_password }}"
    tags:
      Environment: test
  register: cf_stack

- name: task to output stack output
  debug: msg={{ cf_stack }}
  when: debug is defined
```

---

Error at line `debug: msg={{ cf_stack }}` saying:

```
This module prints statements during execution and can be useful for debugging variables or expressions without necessarily halting the playbook. Useful for debugging together with the 'when:' directive.

This module is also supported for Windows targets.

Incorrect type. Expected "object".
```

---

Ansible documentation allows the above syntax, as shown [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html)

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.5.1
....
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: i can't seem to replicate this in plain mac terminal, how do you run your playbook?

Comment: @letthefireflieslive you have the details here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59402057/3317808

Answer (score 1):

You still need to remember quotes for lines starting with a `{`, even when using short-hand notation:

```
- debug: msg="{{ cf_stack }}"
```

This would be more obvious using full YAML notation:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ cf_stack }}"
```

Also, given this is a variable, you could just do:

```
-  debug:
     var: cf_stack
```

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/59402057/3317808